# Why does my firewall reset upon reboot?

Tags: 14.04, iptables, ufw

I host gameservers on my dedicated server and was setting up the firewall a few days ago (had to set everything up again, hard drive failed and I forgot to back-up).

Everything ran fine, firewall rules worked properly, until I had to reboot the server.
I rebooted the server using the standard `reboot` command, and the server never came back up.

I contacted my provider who looked at it, and observed that the rules in `iptables` were completely reset, blocking *every* port on the server.

I had enabled the firewall via `sudo ufw enable` and had added the relevant in `iptables` ([as seen here](https://serverfault.com/questions/594835/what-is-the-correct-way-to-open-a-range-of-ports-in-iptables)):

```
sudo ufw enable
sudo iptables -A INPUT -d 85.25.95.217/32 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -d 85.25.95.217/32 -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -d 85.25.95.217/32 -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -d 85.25.110.75/32 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DROP
sudo iptables -A INPUT -d 85.25.110.75/32 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DROP
sudo iptables -A INPUT -d 85.25.116.59/32 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DROP
sudo iptables -A INPUT -d 85.25.116.59/32 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DROP
sudo iptables -A INPUT -d 188.138.110.103/32 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DROP
sudo iptables -A INPUT -d 188.138.110.103/32 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DROP
sudo iptables -A INPUT -d 85.25.110.75/32 -p tcp --dport 8880 -j DROP
sudo iptables -A INPUT -d 85.25.110.75/32 -p tcp --dport 8881 -j DROP
sudo iptables -A INPUT -d 85.25.116.59/32 -p tcp --dport 8880 -j DROP
sudo iptables -A INPUT -d 85.25.116.59/32 -p tcp --dport 8881 -j DROP
sudo iptables -A INPUT -d 188.138.110.103/32 -p tcp --dport 8880 -j DROP
sudo iptables -A INPUT -d 188.138.110.103/32 -p tcp --dport 8881 -j DROP
sudo iptables-save > /etc/network/iptables.rules
reboot
```

In my `interfaces` file I have put `pre-up iptables-restore < /etc/network/iptables.rules` at the end.

What did I do wrong, or if I didn't do anything wrong, why did `ufw` reset/block all ports when the server was rebooted?

Comment: You can greatly simplify your work using UFW as the only port you are rejecting is port 80. So you need just a single rule too block port 80 in UFW and accept all the rest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay so if you use `iptables` from the command line you they don't get restored on reload or reboot.

You can ever set your firewall rules with `ufw` instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW) **or** if you really need to use `iptables` you need to save your rules to file and have them restored back before your network comes up, you should also disable `ufw` as bodhi.zazen suggested so:

```
sudo ufw disable # You don't want UFW managaing your firewall if you are.
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --match multiport --dports 1:79 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --match multiport --dports 81:65535 -j ACCEPT
sudo sh -c "iptables-save > /etc/iptables.rules"
```

Assuming you have setup your network interfaces by using `/etc/network/interfaces`

Find your stub for your interface and add the following to the stanza:

```
pre-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules
```

e.g.

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
pre-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules
# post-down iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.downrules # if needed
```

[More detailed instructions and variations here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo#Configuration_on_startup)

Comment: good answer, the `Solution #2 /etc/network/if-pre-up.d` from the "more detailed instructions" link works for me. basically 1. create your `/etc/iptables.rules` file as Shutupsquare says 2. make a script `/etc/network/if-pre-up.d/iptablesload` which runs iptables rules. it will load on reboot. I dont have any need for post-down rules, so I don't bother with that.

Comment: If you are going to use iptables directly like this you should disable UFW, otherwise the two tools are trying to configure your firewall at the same time.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen You are correct, I neglected to say that. Thanks I have added it in.

Comment: No longer the accepted answer as this no longer answers the question.

Comment: @ʎǝʞuoɯɹǝqʎɔ Thanks but with yesterdays edit I think it would answer the question. Disabling `ufw`

Comment: @Shutupsquare I thought `ufw` managed `iptables`, or are they two completely different things?

Comment: @ʎǝʞuoɯɹǝqʎɔ It does, that's why he needs to turn it off, if he wants to manage `iptables` himself.

Comment: @Shutupsquare So that's the reason when I enable `ufw` and set my firewall rules then reboot, it's blocking all the ports (including SSH)?

Comment: @ʎǝʞuoɯɹǝqʎɔ Yes you turn ufw then you block everything unless you tell it not too (using `ufw`).